# Questions on coarea formula

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

The coarea formula asserts that if $u:\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz and $g\in L^1$, then we have
$$ 
\int_{\Omega}g(x)|\nabla u(x)|dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{u(x)=\zeta}g(x)dS_{n}(x)d\zeta
$$

where $dS_{n}(x)$ is the Hausdorff measure on the hypersurface $\{u(x)=\zeta\}$. My questions are: First of all, is the Hausdorff measure here coincides with the Lebesgue measure of the surface provided that $u$ is "good" enough? Secondly, how can one prove this using only undergraduate math, say, multivariable calculus for such a function  $u$(one may consider the case when $u$ is smooth)? Thanks for help!

Comment: [Now crossposted to MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/q/135456/1916).